# How do you fmap a Getter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

As [discussed on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1nilcr/lift_a_datalens_to_work_across_maybe/), you can't just lift a `Lens' a b` to `Lens' (Maybe a) (Maybe b)`. But for the special case `Getter a b`, this is obviously possible, since it's isomorphic to `a->b`. But unlike with `Iso`, there appears to be no standard function to perform this lift.

What's the preferred way to do that? In cases like

```
    someFunction $ myMap^.at(i).ꜰᴍᴀᴘGᴇᴛ(mySubGetter)
```

I could of course do

```
    someFunction $ myMap^.at(i) & fmap (^.mySubGetter)
```

but that doesn't work as well in other applications, as when operating on a state monad.

```
    foo <- use $ myMapInState.at(i).ꜰᴍᴀᴘGᴇᴛ(mySubGetter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you want with a prism.

If your values have these types:

```
myMap :: Map String (Int, String)
myMap = mempty

mySubGetter :: Lens' (Int, String) String
mySubGetter = _2
```

then you can do:

```
myVal :: Maybe String
myVal = myMap ^? at "myKey" . _Just . mySubGetter
```

If you just want to apply a function to a getter you can use the `to` function from [Control.Lens.Getter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html), you have to manually deal with the sublens though:

```
someFunction $ myMap ^. at(i) . to (fmap (^. mySubGetter))
```

Comment: This is excellent. I suppose I couldn't use prisms for the general `Functor` case, could I?

Comment: No you cannot have a Prism for any Functor because you need to be able to unpack the value to make the prism. A _IO prism for example is impossible. If you only care about Getting you can make your ``mapGet`` function like this: ``mapGet l = to (fmap (view l))``. A Prism is more powerful than a Getter because it allows you to maybe set a value as well as get it.